# Read styles from json file into javascript for Google Maps rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to read the data from a local JSON file into a styles variable to pass as a parameter to the Google Maps API JavaScript constructor.

```
// Create a styles array to use with the map.
var styles = $.getJSON('../styles.json', function(data){
    console.log(data.styles);         //(1)
    return data.styles;
});

console.log(styles);                  //(2)

// Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: defaultValue.coords.lat, lng: defaultValue.coords.lng },
    zoom: 13,
    styles: styles,
    mapTypeControl: false
});
```

When I log the data being read inside the success function (1), I get the array in the following picture with 26 items, which is what I want. But when I `console.log()` the styles array outside of the ajax function (2), I get a null object. I think this is a problem with the `$.getJSON()` call which by default loads the data asynchronously. But even when I use the `$.ajax()` method and specify `async: false`, I get the same result.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

1. `getJSON` return a `jqXHR` object and not the result of the operation. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)
2. It's asynchronous so your `console.log()` and your `map` creation are called before the callback of your `getJSON`.

So your code should look like this:

```
$.getJSON('../styles.json', function(data){
    console.log(data.styles);         //(1)
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: {lat: defaultValue.coords.lat, lng: defaultValue.coords.lng },
       zoom: 13,
       styles: data.styles,
       mapTypeControl: false
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@ADreNaLiNe-DJ

Unfortunately, I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsClU.png) when I try to use your suggestion.

However, I was able to solve the problem like this:

```
var styles = [];

// populate styles array with styles from 'styles.json'
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: '../styles.json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        styles = data.styles;
    }
});

// Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: defaultValue.coords.lat, lng: defaultValue.coords.lng },
    zoom: 13,
    styles: styles,
    mapTypeControl: false
});
```